# rsync, symbols not resolved but libraries found

Tags: linux, rsync, libraries, symbols

In an embedded system I can't run rsync:

```
$ rsync 
/usr/bin/rsync: symbol 'poptHelpOptions': can't resolve symbol
/usr/bin/rsync: symbol '_poptBitsN': can't resolve symbol
/usr/bin/rsync: symbol '_poptArgMask': can't resolve symbol
/usr/bin/rsync: symbol '_poptBitsK': can't resolve symbol
/usr/bin/rsync: symbol '_poptBitsM': can't resolve symbol
/usr/bin/rsync: symbol 'poptAliasOptions': can't resolve symbol
/usr/bin/rsync: symbol 'poptHelpOptionsI18N': can't resolve symbol
```

but it seems the dependencies are found:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/rsync 
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x76f36000)
    libpopt.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpopt.so.0 (0x76f1b000)
    libc.so.1 => /lib/libc.so.1 (0x76ea2000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x76d61000)
    ld-linux-armhf.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0x76d30000)
    ld-uClibc.so.1 => /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 (0x76f57000)
```

Is there something else that would lead to those errors?
This is a Buildroot environment (kernel 4.4.8-v7) on armv7l.

Comment: Not all variants of a given `.so` have all the same functions available. Maybe a newer version or different distribution of `libpopt.so` (the library that the missing functions are likely supposed to be in) is necessary.

Comment: You put me on the right track. I double checked the popt library and I discovered the actual lib installed on the target was different than the one in the cross-compile environment. Copying the more recent one (I guess from the last build) fixed the issue.